# In java cups library want to fetch all the jobs attributes of given print job with the completion time?

Tags: java, attributes, jobs, cups, cups4j

I want to fetch cups all data job attributes i.e (job-id, job-name, job-state and job-completion-time)

Repo : https://github.com/harwey/cups4j
There are two methods to fetch :

1. In [IppGetJobsOperation->getPrintJobs()] First method fetch all cups jobs attributes but attributes job completion date contains null.
2. In [IppGetJobAttributesOperation->getPrintJobAttributes()] Also there is another method in which if we give a particular job id it gives the job attributes with job completion time.

Is there any other way to fetch all jobs attributes with the job completion time.